# Extracting Excel table column span value into a Word doc 'gridSpan' element using XSLT 2.0 and Saxon-PE 9.2.0.6

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Using XSLT 2.0 in Saxon-PE 9.2.0.6, I need to pull from an Excel data sheet.xml into an element ‘w:gridSpan’ the number of spanned columns in Row 2 using the values from the sheet’s mergecells element. Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to do this?

The input XML is this:

```
    <row r="2" spans="1:6" ht="33" customHeight="1">
        <c r="A2" s="6" t="s">
            <v>33</v>
        </c>
        <c r="B2" s="12" t="s">
            <v>0</v>
        </c>
        <c r="C2" s="13"/>
        <c r="D2" s="13"/>
        <c r="E2" s="13"/>
        <c r="F2" s="13"/>
    </row>

    …………

<mergeCells count="2">
    <mergeCell ref="B1:F1"/>
    <mergeCell ref="B2:F2"/>
</mergeCells>
```

The portion of my XSLT pertaining to the input XML:

```
        <w:tc>
          <w:tcPr>
            <w:vAlign w:val="bottom"/>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="**e:sheetData/e:row[position() = 2]**">
                <xsl:element name="w:gridSpan">
                  <xsl:attribute name="w:val">
                    <xsl:value-of select="**dg3:get_column_span**"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
```

Desired output:

```
        <w:tc>
           <w:tcPr>
              <w:vAlign w:val="bottom"/>
              <w:gridSpan w:val="1"/>
           </w:tcPr>
```

I have also had suggested use of the following two functions, but do not know how to implement them to obtain the number of columns spanned in row 2 example of spreadsheet rows 1 and 2, and the suggested 2 funcs follow:

```
A       B       C        D        E        F
    Optimum Fixed Income Fund Class A

    Year Ended


  <xsl:function name="dg3:get_column_span">
    <xsl:param name="cell"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$mergeCells[e:mergeCell[matches(@ref, concat('^',$cell/@r,':'))]]">
        <xsl:variable name="merge"
          select="$mergeCells//e:mergeCell[matches(@ref, concat('^',$cell/@r,':'))]"/>
        <xsl:value-of
          select="dg3:get_column_number(replace($merge/@ref, '([^:]+):([^;]+)','$2')) -
          dg3:get_column_number(replace($merge/@ref, '([^:]+):([^;]+)','$1')) + 1"
        />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="dg3:get_column_number">
    <xsl:param name="range"/>
    <xsl:value-of
      select="string-to-codepoints(substring($range,1,1)) -
      string-to-codepoints('A') + 1"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the expected result in this example, and what is logic required to obtain it? IOW, how would you do this if you had to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are trying to start from, which would dictate the precise route but:

```
<xsl:attribute name="w:val">
<xsl:value-of select="mergeCells/@count"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Gets that 2 for you...

Also I'm confused why you are using when/choose here and it isn't a straight template match.

Comment: actually, what I'm trying to get is the number of columns spanned between the spreadsheet columns B2 and F2 in <mergeCell ref="B2:F2"/>, if that clarifies it a bit.